# Python uses the unpack function of the strike module to decode double floating point numbers

Tags: python, struct, unpack

I am using unpack to parse a piece of data, this is a byte stream in it
(`\x31\x2e\x91\x5a\x8a\x20\xbd\x3e`),this corresponds to the double floating-point number in the figure below,I unpack according to type "`d`"，but the result is too small(`1.736111111111111e-06`).
According to the decoded picture, `the data should be the number of days since 12/30/1899 or the number of days since the data was collected, which should not be so small.` I guess it's code usage. I should have looked for a lot of information, but I couldn't find a way. If anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

[image: decode]

These are examples of my code, where I extract the absolute time portion of the data separately and decode it.

```
import struct
data1 = b'\x31\x2e\x91\x5a\x8a\x20\xbd\x3e'
data2 = b"\x21\x74\x0b\xe7\x06\x6b\xc3\x3e"

decoded_data1 = struct.unpack("d",data1)[0]
decoded_data2 = struct.unpack("d",data2)[0]
print(decoded_data1)
print(decoded_data2)
```

The result:

```
1.736111111111111e-06
2.3148148148148148e-06
```

Comment: I would suggest an endianness issue, but you are already decoding it as little-endian. (Switching to big-endian gives you an even smaller value, so I suspect the eight bytes you are showing aren't actually the bytes at offset 28 of the larger stream.)

Comment: @baixianjie It might be useful if you could show the code where you extract these values from the data stream

Comment: @chepnerI can guarantee that the bytes I got are correct. I compared them one by one according to the data encoding table, so I am very confused why the decoded data is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure it’s not "number of days since start of acquisition"? 1.7361 microdays works out to suspiciously close to 0.15 seconds,